# Why LIBOR discount and continuous compounding discount are different?

Tags: interest-rate-swap, discounting

[image]
[image]

The reference is Fixed Income Securities by Pietro Veronesi.

As you can see, In Table 20.5 when the maturity is 1.25, the LIBOR Discount is 96.7402
However In Table 20.3 with same maturity, the continuous compounding discount is 96.7385

Even it is the data from same date November 1, 2004

I think those two should be the same for no arbitrage. I already know when the frequency is changed, the yield should also be changed. But the background is that : Because the **discount is same**, the only one source that makes the difference is 'frequency'.

So I think although the frequency of LIBOR discount is different with Continuously compounding, the discount should be the same.

How it is derived the number 96.7402?

Comment: The continuously compounded rates we can calculate from those two slightly different discount factors are $2.6513\%$ and $2.6527\%$. The difference is only $0.14$ basis points. I suspect it is a minor numerical "issue".